# Sending keyboard presses to another computer?

Tags: java, keyboard

I was wondering if i could get help making or finding a program that has the ability to send keyboard presses and receive them on another computer. I want to use this to play multiplayer flash-player games with friends across computers. I know there are some programs out there like "logmein" but both users cannot use the keyboard at the same time. (When i press a key the computer user cannot press a key at the same time because it wont respond.) I only know java and I am quite novice at it. Im guessing if i need to write it ill have to send the information through a port or onto a web-server. I would like to know your opinions and suggestions for this program, thanks guys.

Comment: Couldn't you just store which keys are pressed as booleans and then send them via udp or tcp in byte form?

Comment: would that have lag? and im not sure ill look into it. That is somewhere along the lines of what i was thinking to do.

Comment: The Java code itself won't introduce lag.......your internet connection on the other hand.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for is a chatroom program?  Have you tried looking into mIRC?
mIRC is a free internet relay chat.  What exactly are the requirements for the program?  Is there a certain size that it must be?  Are these flash games that you and your friends are playing taking up your full computer screen?

Building a program would require a web-server(any computer with internet access would do), and you would have to open the ports on your network to allow the traffic to go through.

A basic server in java would look something like this:
Please note that after the first connection this "server" will close the connection.

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Server
{
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String inputLine;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Wait for client to connect on 63400
    try
    {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(63400);
                    while(true){
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        // Create a reader
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        // Get the client message
        while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    {System.out.println(inputLine);}
    serverSocket.close();
            System.out.println("close");
                    }
            }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

And a client would almost be the same:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class client
{
private static Socket socket;
private static PrintWriter printWriter;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
                   //change "localhost" to the ip address that the client is on, and this number to the port
        socket = new Socket("localhost",63400);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        printWriter.println("Hello Socket");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

If I am not mistaken printWriter is a 16-bit operation, and in order to reduce lag, if you were just sending text then you might want to use printStream().  I believe that this might be a bit quicker.